# Elasticsearch snapshot cannot be done on DFS mounted drive

Tags: elasticsearch, snapshot

I need to backup some index in my Elasticsearch and I would like to use options in Kibana to save/restore snapshots. I have already mount DFS share in to /mn/elk on all nodes (data and also masters nodes) and put repo.path in to elasticsearc.yml.

Everything seems to be ok but I have a problem that the snapshot task cannot be perfom because elasticsearch user probably does not have enough rights to folder where disk is mounted (when you mount disk it is always mounted under root). The permissions on that folders are: drwxr-xr-x. Please do you know how to manage this rights? Or this si not a problem and problem is something else?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

the way how to fix it was mount that DFS share under elasticsearch user and correct rigts 775.